# how can I simulate connection lost with xampp?

Tags: php, ajax, xampp, connection, simulation

Is there a way to simulate connection lost on xampp?
I'm not sure how to handle errors that never happens.
I'm using ajax to php scripts calls and I want to know what will happen if my connection will be lost.

Comment: Access your page, then shut the webserver down, then trigger the ajax call

Comment: You want to show a message if connection is not working to database right? if it's what you are looking for , in your connection file ,mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'dbuser', 'dbpass') or die('Could not connect to mysql server.' );